# Calculate hex after hue-rotate has been applied?

Tags: javascript, css, colors

Suppose I set the color of a div like this:

```
div_a.style.backgroundColor = "#5D8233";
```

And then I apply a filter like this:

```
div_a.style.filter = 'hue-rotate(' + rotator + 'deg)';
```

How would I calculate the hex of the div after the filter has been applied?

The div contains only one color

Comment: you need to do the calculation by yourself, check this: https://jsfiddle.net/Camilo/dd6feyh6/

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the `getComputedStyle` method.

It would look something like this:

```js
let computedColor = window.getComputedStyle(div_a).backgroundColor
```